# Python, email, quoted-printable partially decoded on other end

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I don't understand why the body of my email I send via Python and the email library isn't being decoded by the receiving mail server.  I know I've done something wrong, but don't know what.  CTE is `Quoted-Printable`, and when viewing the raw email, it's still encoded.
I'm burning the net up, but most of my results deal with the legacy API of the email library.  I use the current version, because it's recommended and more robust.

Code to package EmailMessage:

```
    """
    @type sndr: str
    @type rcvr: str
    @type subj: str
    @type body: tuple
    @type extra: tuple
    @return: bytes
    """
    msg = message.EmailMessage()
    if '<' in sndr:
        name, sep, addr = sndr.rpartition(' ')  # Partition at space between display name & address
        name = name.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing spaces
        addr = addr.strip('<>')  # Remove leading and trailing angle brackets
        msg['From'] = headerregistry.Address(display_name=name, addr_spec=addr)
    else:
        msg['From'] = headerregistry.Address(display_name='', addr_spec=sndr)
    if '<' in rcvr:
        name, sep, addr = rcvr.rpartition(' ')
        name = name.strip()
        addr = addr.strip('<>')
        msg['To'] = headerregistry.Address(display_name=name, addr_spec=addr)
    else:
        msg['To'] = headerregistry.Address(display_name='', addr_spec=rcvr)
    msg['Subject'] = subj
    msg.set_content(body[0], charset='utf-8')
    msg.add_alternative(body[1], cte='quoted-printable', subtype='html')
    return msg
```

HTML body:

```
    """
    @type body: str
    @return: str
    """
    first = \
        '<html><head>\r' \
        '<meta http–equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\r' \
        '</head>'
    second = f'<body><div>{body}</div></body></html>'
    payload = first + second
    return payload
```

By using the argument `subtype='html'`, Python creates the required `meta` tags.  These tags display correctly in the raw email, yet my tags (old/troubleshooting code, no need to focus on it—the problem remains) do not.  The en dash between "http" and "equiv" displays encoded.  What's wrong.  I want to send email using the full `utf-8` range.

Also, I use the following from `smtplib` to send the message: `send_message(msg)`.  So, the default call of `send_message()`.

Comment: "when viewing the raw email, it's still encoded" - I would expect that the "raw message" would not perform any decoding.

Comment: Yeah, I started to come to that conclusion after I saw that a long line had equals at the break.  But, I was thrown because the meta attributes of an HTML email added by Python were not encoded.  I just don't really know.  I moved on assuming what you said is the case.  If future info changes my current thoughts, I'll see where it goes.  Thanks.